# realpath: --relative-base and --relative-to

Tags: coreutils

From coreutils about `realpath`

> `--relative-to=file` Print the resolved file names relative to the
>   specified file. Note this option honors the `-m` and `-e` options
>   pertaining to file existence.
>
> `--relative-base=base` This option is valid when used with
>   `--relative-to`, and will restrict the output of `--relative-to` so
>   that relative names are output, only when files are descendants of
>   base. Otherwise output the absolute file name. If `--relative-to` was
>   not specified, then the descendants of base are printed relative to
>   base. If `--relative-to` is specified, then that directory must be a
>   descendant of base for this option to have an effect. Note: this
>   option honors the `-m` and `-e` options pertaining to file existence.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> realpath --relative-to=/usr /tmp /usr/bin
> ⇒ ../tmp
> ⇒ bin
> realpath --relative-base=/usr /tmp /usr/bin
> ⇒ /tmp
> ⇒ bin
> ```

1. Does "This option is valid when used with `--relative-to`" mean that
   `--relative-base` can't work without `--relative-to` specified?

   Then why does it also say later that "If `--relative-to` was  not
   specified, then the descendants of base are printed relative to 
   base", which implies that `--relative-base` can work without
   `--relative-to` specified?
2. "If `--relative-to` was  not specified, then the descendants of base
   are printed relative to  base. If `--relative-to` is specified, then
   that directory must be a  descendant of base for this option to have
   an effect."

   What are the differences between the two cases with and without
   `--relative-to` specified?

   In the quote, are the two cases  the same, in the sense that only
   the descendants of base are printed relative to base, while others
   are printed as absolute pathnames?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The developers found this obscure and changed it more than four years ago:

- [realpath: optimize --relative-base usage](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/realpath.c?id=be17e3b98a178ea6e2c973bf49282f11f7060353) (2012-03-15)

> There is no need to recompute for every path being visited whether the base is a prefix of the relative location.

- [realpath: let **`--relative-to`** default to **`--relative-base`**](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/realpath.c?id=9f5aa4850133976eee22dcc0b506d7b632cd674c) (2012-03-15)

> Most of the time, if someone wants to filter which paths are relative while leaving all others absolute, they also want to to the filtering based on the same **`--relative-to`** directory. Make this easier to specify.

But the documentation for [`--relative-base`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/doc/coreutils.texi#n13688) and `--relative-to` appears to have [not been reworded to clarify](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/doc/coreutils.texi?id=9f5aa4850133976eee22dcc0b506d7b632cd674c) that if `--relative-to` was not specified, then it defaults to the value given for `--relative-base`.